# Operador AND em regex

Tags: java, regex

Tenho o seguinte formato data/hora:

**25/01/2017às11:53:37**

E a seguinte regex:

> REGX_DATAHORA_DISTRIBUICAO =  `"(?<data>\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})|(?<hora>\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})"`

```
    private OffsetDateTime getDataDistribuicao() {
    String textoData = replaceAndTrim(this.getPaginaInfoGerais().<HtmlTableCell>getFirstByXPath(XPATH_CEL_DATA_DISTRIBUICAO)
            .getTextContent());
    return LocalDateTime
            .parse(getDataDistribuicao(textoData),
                    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(PATTERN_DATA_HORA))
            .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
}

private String getDataDistribuicao(final String dataTexto)  {
    final Matcher matcherDataHora = REGX_DATAHORA_DISTRIBUICAO.matcher(dataTexto);
    if (matcherDataHora.find()) {
        return matcherDataHora.group();
    } else {
        throw new RegexException("Data distribuição", REGX_DATAHORA_MOVIMENTACAO.pattern(), dataTexto);
    }
}
```

A regex possui 2 grupos, porém só é retornado um grupo, o da data.. O outro grupo de hora retorna como null.
Imagino que seja por conta do operador...
 já tentei usar `(?=`(`positive lookahead`), mas talvez tenha usado de forma errada.
 **O que fazer?**

Comment: qual formato de saída pós regex você quer chegar?

Comment: um OffsetDateTime, acrescentei o outro método utilizado.

Comment: https://ideone.com/S81daa

Comment: O motivo é simples, você esta dando `return`, antes de percorrer todos os grupos. `if (matcherDataHora.find()) { return matcherDataHora.group(); }`, ou seja você apenas verificou se deu `match` e deu `return` no primeiro grupo.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert sim, esse return faltou concatenar. Mas mesmo assim, o grupo 2 se você validar, está nulo. Essa mesma situação encontrei no forum gringo. Mesmo retornando os dois grupos concatenados, o 2 fica nulo do mesmo modo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom, pelo que pesquisei, esse problema se dá ao fato do operador | (OR) no Java considerar apenas um grupo mesmo. Então, o que fiz foi contornar isso como vi em alguns fóruns:

```
    private String getDataDistribuicao(final String dataTexto)  {
    String[] grupos = dataTexto.split("às");
    StringBuilder dataHora = new StringBuilder();
    for(String grupo: grupos){
        final Matcher matcherDataHora = REGX_DATAHORA_DISTRIBUICAO.matcher(grupo);
        if (matcherDataHora.find()) {
            dataHora.append(" ").append(grupo);
        } else {
            throw new RegexException("Data distribuição", REGX_DATAHORA_DISTRIBUICAO.pattern(), dataTexto);
        }
    }
    return dataHora.toString();
}
```

Comment: muito bom, não tinha pensado nisso +1

Answer (score 2):

> Ele possui 2 grupos, porém os dois grupos retornam apenas a parte da
>   data: 25/01/2017.

Na verdade seus grupos retornam coisas diferentes:

1. `(?<data>\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4})` - Retorna: **25/01/2017**
2. `(?<hora>\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})` - Retorna: **11:53:37**

Fiz um teste para comprovar isso, você pode ver ele [aqui](http://fiddle.re/93kfrd).

> Imagino que seja por conta do operador

Na verdade acredito que não esteja retornando o resultado inteiro porque você está usando o método `Matcher.group()`, esse método retorna os matchs de um grupo de captura específico, você pode ler a documentação sobre o uso dele [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html).

> O que fazer?

Você pode usar:

```
private String getDataDistribuicao(final String dataTexto)  {
    final Matcher matcherDataHora = REGX_DATAHORA_DISTRIBUICAO.matcher(dataTexto);
    if (matcherDataHora.find()) {
        StringBuilder dataHora = new StringBuilder();
 dataHora.append(matcherDataHora.group("data")).append(matcherDataHora.group("hora"));
        return dataHora.toString;
    } else {
        throw new RegexException("Data distribuição", REGX_DATAHORA_MOVIMENTACAO.pattern(), dataTexto);
    }
}
```

Caso não funcione, sugiro que tente debugar os valores de retorno `matcherDataHora.group("data")` e `matcherDataHora.group("hora")`, caso 1 dos dois retornos esteja vazio, cheque se o valor de entrada que você colocou aqui está correto, pois a regex deveria capturar esse padrão.

Comment: Sim, eu testei no Rubular essa expressão e volta os dois grupos distintos mesmo. Mas no debug, os grupos 1 e 2 voltam com a data mesmo. O problema não é na concatenação, é no valor mesmo que vem apenas a data. Coloquei o outro método que é utilizado para melhor entender. Obrigada

Comment: Talvez tenha me equivocado sobre o erro estar no regex

Comment: quando você debuga e vai nos grupos 1 e 2, eles apresentam o mesmo content?

Comment: acho esquisito ambos retornarem a mesma coisa visto que o segundo grupo de captura não aceitaria o formato de data xx/xx/xxxx, porque necessita dar match em ":"

Comment: sim, os grupos (0) e (1) retornam mesmo content

Comment: @Laryssa ahhhh, isso é diferente, grupo 0 denota "Full match", enquanto o 1 é só o grupo de captura 1, então o problema é que seu grupo 2 não está dando match

Comment: Ah sim, entendi.. bom, o grupo(2) retorna nulo. Estranho que testei essa regex no rubular com o mesmo texto: 25/01/2017às11:53:37 e ele dá match nos 2 grupos...

Comment: @Laryssa E eu testei no RegexPlanet e realmente da match, vamos tentar resolver esse problema via chat?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66827/discussion-between-paz-and-laryssa).

Comment: @Paz o link do seu fiddle está morto :\