# Operador "AND" em Regex

Tags: php, regex

Estou tentando utilizar o operador `AND` em regex. Já procurei [nesse link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/244608/operador-and-em-regex), mas este caso não me ajudou. Meu caso é, por exemplo, no texto:

```
"FORT/310117/200826/12979898000170"
```

Quero que retorne os números com exatamente 6 dígitos e retorne o número com exatamente 14 dígitos. Se um ou outro não existir, não quero que retorne nada (por isso a necessidade do operador "AND"). Ou seja, se o exemplo for:

```
"FORT/310117/200826" ou "FORT/12979898000170"
```

não retorna nada.

O regex que estou utilizando é com o `or` e ele retorna caso encontre 6 ou 14 dígitos. Como poderia alterá-lo para o `AND`?

```
(\b\d{6}\b)|(\b\d{14}\b)
```

Comment: Qual linguagem de programação usa?

Comment: Utilizo a linguagem PHP

Comment: Um exemplo em javascript te ajuda?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Uma alternativa é usar [*lookaheads*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(?=.*\b\d{6}\b)(?=.*\b\d{14}\b)
```

Cada *lookahead* é delimitado por `(?=` e `)` e a ideia dele é: o *lookahead* procura pela expressão que está dentro dele, e caso encontre, **volta para onde estava** e continua avaliando o restante da regex.

No caso, a expressão dentro do primeiro *lookahead* `(?=.*\b\d{6}\b)` significa:

- `.*`: zero ou mais caracteres (qualquer caractere)
- `\b`: [*word-boundary*](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) ("fronteira de palavra"), o que quer dizer que é a posição da string que delimita uma palavra (ou seja, há um caractere alfanumérico antes e um não-alfanumérico depois - ou vice-versa).
- `\d{6}`: exatamente 6 dígitos
- `\b`: outra *word-boundary*. Com isso, indicamos que os 6 dígitos estão delimitados por caracteres não-alfanuméricos (não correndo o risco de pegar sequências maiores que 6 dígitos).

Este *lookahead* está logo depois do [marcador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^`, que significa "início da string". Ou seja, se o *lookahead* encontrar uma sequência de 6 dígitos em algum lugar da string, ele volta para onde estava (no caso, para o início da string) e continua avaliando o restante da regex.

No caso, o restante da regex é outro *lookahead*, bem parecido com o primeiro, mas que busca uma sequência de exatamente 14 dígitos.

Ou seja, esta regex primeiro verifica se há uma sequência de 6 dígitos. Como `\d{6}` está em um *lookahead*, ele volta para o início da string e avalia o segundo *lookahead*, que procura uma sequência de 14 dígitos.

Se qualquer um dos *lookaheads* falhar, a regex como um todo também falha. Exemplo:

```
$regex = '/^(?=.*\b\d{6}\b)(?=.*\b\d{14}\b)/';

echo preg_match($regex, "FORT/310117/200826/12979898000170") . "\n"; // 1
echo preg_match($regex, "FORT/310117/200826/") . "\n"; // 0
echo preg_match($regex, "FORT/12979898000170") . "\n"; // 0
```

[`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php#refsect1-function.preg-match-returnvalues) retorna 1 se a regex encontra um *match* e *zero* caso não encontre. No caso acima, retornou 1 apenas para o caso em que há as duas sequências (de 6 e 14 dígitos). Para os casos em que há apenas uma delas, retorna 0.

Esta regex também não aceita sequências de 7 dígitos, por exemplo:

```
// tem sequência de 14, mas não tem de 6 (somente de 7)
echo preg_match($regex, "FORT/3101176/12979898000170") . "\n"; // 0
```

---

Se o delimitador sempre for `/`, você pode trocar `\b` pela barra:

```
$regex = '/^(?=.*\/\d{6}(\/|$))(?=.*\/\d{14}(\/|$))/';
```

A diferença neste caso é que a barra deve ser escapada e escrita como `\/` (para não ser confundida com o delimitador de regex no início e fim da string). Além disso, depois da sequência de dígitos coloquei `(\/|$)`, que significa "uma barra **ou** o final da string (`$`)" (com `\b` isso não é necessário, pois `\b` já considera o final da string como uma *word-boundary*).

---

### "Split" em vez de super-regex-que-faz-tudo

A regex acima só valida se a string possui tais sequências de dígitos. Mas se quiser pegar os dígitos propriamente ditos, acho mais fácil quebrar a string e percorrer as partes uma a uma:

```
$partes = explode("/", "FORT/310117/200826/12979898000170");
$temSequenciaDe6 = false;
$temSequenciaDe14 = false;
foreach ($partes as $parte) {
    if (preg_match('/^\d{6}$/', $parte)) {
        $temSequenciaDe6 = true;
        echo $parte . "\n";
    } else if (preg_match('/^\d{14}$/', $parte)) {
        $temSequenciaDe14 = true;
        echo $parte . "\n";
    }
}
```

Neste caso as expressões são mais simples. `^\d{6}$`, por exemplo, verifica exatamente 6 dígitos do início (`^`) ao fim (`$`) da string, enquanto `^\d{14}$` verifica exatamente 14 dígitos do início ao fim.

Este código imprime os números que você quer (somente se tiver 6 ou 14 dígitos), e os valores booleanos `$temSequenciaDe6` e `$temSequenciaDe14` indicam quais delas existem na string. Para saber se a string possui ambas, basta fazer:

```
if ($temSequenciaDe6 && $temSequenciaDe14) {
    // string possui sequências de 6 e de 14 dígitos
}
```

---

Também é possível quebrar a string usando uma regex como critério, caso a `/` não seja o único separador. Basta usar [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php):

```
$partes = preg_split('/[\/ ]/', "FORT 310117 200826 12979898000170");
```

Neste caso, a regex será usada para quebrar a string. Como usei `[\/ ]`, isso quer dizer que tanto a `/` quanto o espaço serão usados como delimitadores (repare que há um espaço antes do `]`).

Caso os separadores sejam apenas um caractere, basta adicionar todos os possíveis separadores dentro dos colchetes. Por exemplo, `[\/ ,\-]` considera que o separador pode ser a `/`, **ou** um espaço, **ou** a vírgula, **ou** o hífen. Coloque todos os caracteres que precisar.

Se o separador tiver mais que um caractere, aí é melhor usar [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (`|`). Ex: `( |\/|xyz)` usaria um espaço, ou a barra, ou a string `xyz` como separador. Se os separadores forem apenas um caractere (e não uma string com 2 ou mais), eu acho mais fácil usar os colchetes.

---

#### Outras alternativas

Não consegui uma única regex que faz as duas coisas (valida se há as sequências de 6 e 14 dígitos **e** obtém os números). Mas caso não queira usar `preg_split`, você pode usar a primeira regex acima (com 2 *lookaheads*) para validar a string, e em seguida usar a regex abaixo para obter os números:

```
$str = "FORT/310117/200826/12979898000170";
if (preg_match('/^(?=.*\b\d{6}\b)(?=.*\b\d{14}\b)/', $str)) { 
    preg_match_all('/\b(\d{6}(\d{8})?)\b/', $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    foreach($matches as $m) {
        echo $m[0] . "\n";
    }
}
```

A primeira regex (com os *lookaheads*) valida se a string contém pelo menos uma sequência de 6 dígitos **e** uma de 14 dígitos. Em seguida, a segunda regex obtém todos os números da string que correspondem a estas sequências.

O trecho `(\d{6}(\d{8})?)` significa "6 dígitos, seguidos ou não de 8 dígitos" - o `?` depois de `(\d{8})` torna todo este trecho opcional. Ou seja, esta regex pega tanto 6 quanto 14 dígitos (e o `\b` antes e depois garante que não pegará dígitos a mais). E como a regex anterior (com os *lookaheads*) já garantiu que ambas as sequências existem, eu não preciso me preocupar em verificar isso novamente. A saída deste código é:

```
310117
200826
12979898000170
```

---

**Mais uma opção**

Outra opção é usar uma regex para capturar os grupos de 6 dígitos (garantindo que exista pelo menos um grupo de 14 dígitos), e em seguida outra regex para fazer o inverso (capturar os grupos de 14 dígitos, garantindo que haja pelo menos um de 6).

A primeira regex é:

```
(?|(\b\d{6}\b)(?=.+?\b\d{14}\b)|(?<=\b\d{14}\b).+?(\b\d{6}\b))
```

O trecho `(\b\d{6}\b)(?=.+?\b\d{14}\b)` significa:

- `(\b\d{6}\b)`: 6 dígitos (dentro de parênteses para que forme um grupo de captura)
- `(?=.+?\b\d{14}\b)`: *lookahead* para verificar se há alguma sequência de 14 dígitos à frente

E o trecho `(?<=\b\d{14}\b).+?(\b\d{6}\b)` significa:

- `(?<=\b\d{14}\b)`: *lookbehind* para verificar se há uma sequência de 14 dígitos antes da sequência de 6 dígitos.
- `.+?`: quaisquer caracteres. O `+` significa "um ou mais" e o `?` significa que pegará o mínimo de caracteres para satisfazer a expressão
- `(\b\d{6}\b)`: 6 dígitos

Ou seja, a regex inteira verifica se há uma sequência de 14 dígitos antes **ou** depois da sequência de 6 dígitos.

Eu também uso o `(?|`, que significa [*branch reset*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html). Como os 6 dígitos aparecem duas vezes na expressão, isso significa que ela tem 2 possíveis grupos de captura. Se eu não usar o *branch reset*, terei que verificar qual dos 2 grupos está preenchido, mas usando-o eu garanto que sempre será o grupo 1.

Em seguida eu posso usar a mesma lógica para capturar os grupos de 14 dígitos, e usar os *lookaheads* e *lookbehinds* para verificar se existe pelo menos um grupo de 6 dígitos antes ou depois:

```
$str = "FORT/310117/200826/12979898000170";
// pega os grupos de 6 dígitos (verificando se há grupo de 14 dígitos antes ou depois)
preg_match_all('/(?|(\b\d{6}\b)(?=.+?\b\d{14}\b)|(?<=\b\d{14}\b).+?(\b\d{6}\b))/', $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach($matches as $m) {
    echo $m[1] . "\n";
}

// pega os grupos de 14 dígitos (verificando se há grupo de 6 dígitos antes ou depois)
preg_match_all('/(?|(\b\d{14}\b)(?=.+?\b\d{6}\b)|(?<=\b\d{6}\b).+?(\b\d{14}\b))/', $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach($matches as $m) {
    echo $m[1] . "\n";
}
```

O primeiro `foreach` pega os números com 6 dígitos, e o segundo pega os com 14. Os *lookaheads* e *lookbehinds* garantem que ele só pegará uma das sequências se a outra existir (só pega 6 dígitos se existir pelo menos um de 14, e vice-versa).

A saída é:

```
310117
200826
12979898000170
```

Eu tentei juntar as 2 regex acima em uma só, mas ela acabou pulando o segundo número (200826), [veja no IDEONE](https://ideone.com/b7CxK0). Ainda não descobri o motivo, mas de qualquer forma, isso foi o mais próximo que cheguei de uma única regex que pega todos os números e valida se existe pelo menos uma sequência de 6 e outra de 14 dígitos.

Comment: Olá! Muito bom sua explicação!! Muito obrigado!! Ajudou bastante! No entanto, eu preciso dos números e nem sempre ele vem separado por barras. Por isso estou usando expressão regular ao invés de explode, pois acho que daria pra fazer por strlen depois do explode. Mas tenho n casos, como por exemplo "FORT 310117 200826 12979898000170"

Comment: @Christian Neste caso basta usar `preg_split`. Atualizei a resposta com um exemplo

Comment: @Christian Coloquei mais algumas opções na resposta. Se tiver mais algum caso não mencionado e que as regex não cobrem, por favor edite a pergunta e coloque lá.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match-all.php) com a sua regex mesmo, porém dando nome aos grupos. Por exemplo, ao grupo de *6 dígitos* você dá o nome de `d6`, e ao de *14 dígitos*, o nome de `d14`:

```
$string = "FORT/310117/200826/12979898000170";
// ou $string = "FORT 310117 200826 12979898000170";
preg_match_all("/(?<d6>\b\d{6}\b)|(?<d14>\b\d{14}\b)/", $string, $matches);
```

Ou seja, se não encontrar nenhuma sequência de 6 dígitos, o grupo `d6` vai retornar uma array com índices vazios; o mesmo acontece com o grupo `d14`.

Em seguida você usa [preg_grep](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-grep.php) nos dois grupos para verificar se existe alguma entrada na array que não seja vazia:

```
$d6 = preg_grep('/.{1,}/', $matches['d6']);
$d14 = preg_grep('/.{1,}/', $matches['d14']);
```

Usei apenas a regex `.{1,}` que verifica se em algum (ou mais) índice(s) da array possui pelo menos 1 caractere.

Agora é só fazer um `if` simples verificando se as duas variáveis são true (se possui dados). Caso uma delas seja false (não possui dados), o `if` não é atendido:

```
if($d6 && $d14){
   var_dump($d6);
   var_dump($d14);
}
```

O resultado do `$d6` será:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "310117"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "200826"
}
```

e do `$d14` será:

```
array(1) {
  [2]=>
  string(14) "12979898000170"
}
```

Como o índice de `$d14` é `[2]`, você pode converter em string com:

```
$d14 = implode('', $d14);
```

Para pegar os valores de `$d6` você usa `$d6[0]` e `$d6[1]`.

**Código:**

```
$string = "FORT/310117/200826/12979898000170";
preg_match_all("/(?<d6>\b\d{6}\b)|(?<d14>\b\d{14}\b)/", $string, $matches);

$d6 = preg_grep('/.{1,}/', $matches['d6']);
$d14 = preg_grep('/.{1,}/', $matches['d14']);

if($d6 && $d14){

   $d6_1 = $d6[0];
   $d6_2 = $d6[1];
   $d14 = implode('', $d14);

   echo $d6_1 ." / ". $d6_2 ." / ". $d14;
   // saída: 310117 / 200826 / 12979898000170

}
```

**[IODEONE](https://ideone.com/lVxENF)**